# Access data from an Array Multi

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have an Array $testes that recieves two arrays $variavel1 and $variavel2. Then I set:

`$this->set('testes', $testes)`

In View How I can Take the values from `$variavel1` and `$variavel2` ?

I tried `$testes['$variavel1']['field']`, but I got Undefined Index $variavel1

Practical Example:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [ProcuraProdutoPedOnline] => Array ( [cd_familia] => 3 [ds_familia] => ACESSORIOS ) ) [1] => Array ( [ProcuraProdutoPedOnline] => Array ( [cd_familia] => 1 [ds_familia] => CALCADOS ) )
```

and

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [VwEstPedOnline] => Array ( [cd_seq_pedido] => 2034 ) ) [1] => Array ( [VwEstPedOnline] => Array ( [cd_seq_pedido] => 2038 ) )
```

And i'm setting `$testes` like this, `$testes = array($variavel1, $variavel2);`

Images to explain my problem:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: this wont work like this `$testes['$variavel1']['field']` , maybe `$testes[$variavel1]['field']` ?

Comment: Tira as aspas simples quando tiver uma variável .

Comment: Try `$testes[0]['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']`

Comment: I already tried all this ! And I got : Undefined Index... 
With this `$testes[$variavel1]['field']`, I got this : `Use of undefined constant VwEstPedOnline - assumed 'VwEstPedOnline'`

@PedroLobito, Já tentei de diversas formas ! Inclusive essa que voce me disse, mas não funcionou.

Comment: Please be more specific or show some code. What are your examples? `$variavel1` and `$variavel2`? Or 2 examples for `$testes`? Which value do you want to retrieve from this example?

Comment: @caCtus More specific? `$testes` have those `$variavel1` and `$variavel2` inside of it, How Can I Acess the data from `$testes` ? Example, How to Acess `$variavel1` inside of `$testes` ?

Comment: Please show some code. I don't see when you add `$variavel1` to `$testes` here.

Comment: @caCtus Setting `$testes` like this = `$testes = array($variavel1,$variavel2);`

Comment: If you want to access $variavel1: `$variavel1 = $testes[0];`

Comment: You should have a look at [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), especially example #6 to understand how to work with multidimensionnal arrays.

Comment: Just check the following sample: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/754976ca5414f5c5fa6a3d36e53e7dbd78f3399d

Comment: @caCtus The problem is, I Already saw the PhP Doc, And I Tried to acess like that. And doesn't worked !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you first need to know the array structure. Add this to your view and you'll get a list:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($testes);
echo '</pre>';
```

If the result is empty the problem might be in the place where you add $variavel1 and $variavel2 to the variable $testes...

**EDIT 2:** By your example Array:

```
// Result should be 2034
echo $testes['0']['0']['VwEstPedOnline']['cd_seq_pedido'];
```

**EDIT 3** as answer to your question in the comments to this post:

I still don't understand how $variavel1 and $variavel2 are associated. If there is no connection, you don't need to merge them into one array. You can simply use one foreach within another foreach:

In your controller:

```
$familias = $this->ProcuraProdutoPedOnline->find('all', array(
  'fields' => array('cd_familia', 'ds_familia'),
  'order' => 'cd_familia'));
$this->set('familias', $familias);

$cdSeqPeds = $this->VwEstPedOnline->find('all', array(
  'fields' => 'cd_seq_pedido',
  'order' => 'cd_seq_pedido'));
$this->set('cdSeqPeds', $cdSeqPeds);
```

And in your view:

```
foreach ( $familias as $var1 ) {
  echo '<p>'.$var1['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_familia'].':</p>';
  echo '<ul>';
  foreach ( $cdSeqPeds as $var2 ) {
    echo '<li>'.$var2['VwEstPedOnline']['cd_seq_pedido'].'</li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

The result shoul be something like this:

```
ACESSORIOS:
· 2034
· 2038
CALCADOS:
· 2034
· 2038
```

If this doesn't answer your question, please make an example (with english variable names) what you want to get exactly and how the two tables are connected/associated...

Comment: Isn't empty, the value is there, this is the structure : `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [VwEstPedOnline] => Array
                        (
                            [cd_seq_pedido] => 2034
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [VwEstPedOnline] => Array
                        (
                            [cd_seq_pedido] => 2038
                        )

                )`

Comment: Yes, It worked ! But result 2034 comes duplicated and I want to bring all the Array, understand ? All positions. How can I do that ?

Comment: `foreach ( $testes['0'] as $item ) { echo '<p>'.$item['VwEstPedOnline']['cd_seq_pedido'].'</p>'; }`

Comment: And If I want the position [1] on the same foreach, is that possible ??? Whats the difference of `foreach($variavel as $obj)` to `foreach($variavel as key=> $obj)` ??? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Why are you building the $testes array manually? Usually you should use the CakePHP `find('all')` method to build the array the way you need it to run it easyly through a foreach. Please also have a look at example 4 on [this site](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: I Already read that ! And I'm using find('all').. Like this `$familias = $this->ProcuraProdutoPedOnline->find('all', array('fields' => array('cd_familia', 'ds_familia'), 'group' => array('cd_familia', 'ds_familia'), 'order' => 'cd_familia'));`

To you understand, $familias means $variavel1  and $cdSeqPed means $variavel2 from the example.

But I have this too `$cdSeqPeds = $this->VwEstPedOnline->find('all', array('fields' => 'cd_seq_pedido', 'order' => 'cd_seq_pedido', 'group' => 'cd_seq_pedido'));`

Comment: Sorry, language barrier. Could you translate the variables to english please? I don't understand how $familias and $cdSeqPeds are connected. Are the two models/tables [associated](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)? Maybe the [containable behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) is useful? If there is no connection, why do you want to use them in one array?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english hehe... The problem is use an foreach inside of another foreach, understand ? $familias and $cdSeqPed its the example $variavel1 and $variavel2.. Just to explain

Comment: Did you saw my problem ? 
`ACESSORIOS:
· 2034
· 2038
CALCADOS:
· 2034
· 2038`
Repeating the result... That's what I don't want.
I want Like this `.ACESSORIOS . CALCADOS and then 2034 2038`

I will add an image to the principal post.

Comment: And what exactly do you want? How should the result look like?

Comment: I put some images ! The result to every field is like the 2º field.. Nothing repeats.. I'm doing something wrong... How to use 2 foreach , one inside another without duplicate the result?  See the images.

Comment: Thank you - but sorry, I don't understand Portuguese, it's really hard to understand what it's all about...? (Google translator doesn't really help) Why don't you just save the last column "Codigo Filial" in the same table as "Codigo Sequential Pedido" (whatever that means)? Maybe [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) is what you're looking for? But if there is any kind of connection between the two tables, you should associate them (has one/has many/belongs to etc.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77125/discussion-between-edson-rodrigues-and-user1843159).

Comment: No, sorry, I'm out for today, it's late... I gave you multiple hints, please have a look at them. If you currently don't see a solution, please start a new question on Stackoverflow and give a clear (english) example what you have (tables, connections), what you get and what you want to get (with examples)... Good luck! And good night.